# Can Sublime SFTP remember an SSH key passphrase?

Tags: sublimetext3, sftp

When I use [Sublime SFTP](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) to connect to a server via the SFTP protocol, it always prompts for my SSH key passphrase the first time I connect during a given editing session.

Since I work with many sites and use strong passwords, memorizing these passphrases isn't an option. So I have to open a customer's reference document to copy/paste their passphrase each time.

Is there any way to let the plugin remember a passphrase, or to specify it in the .json config file?

Or would that be dangerous for some reason? My machine is well secured, so I'm not overly concerned about keeping the passphrase key in a config file.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: The purpose of a key passphrase is to prevent someone who doesn't know the phrase from using the key. If you're contemplating storing the passphrase in a file along with the key, you might as well just remove the passphrase from the key.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks. When I reviewed SO's rules (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) they say questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are okay, so I thought this would be fine. There are several thousand other questions about how to use Sublime, which also suggested this was a reasonable question. No? To be clear: I'm not asking someone to fix a bad package installation. I'm hoping other experienced Sublime programmers have advice on how to configure SFTP to work more smoothly in Sublime as I develop web applications for my clients.

Comment: Thanks @Kenster. My goal in using SFTP is to secure network traffic as I iteratively save and upload files to a remote server. Though nothing's invulnerable, I'm not so concerned with my workstation's file security. And FWIW, the passphrase and the key would be in different places, though both on the same (encrypted) filesystem.

Comment: Has anyone managed to use SFTP without passphrase prompt? I've been able to do it with 'password' directive in sftp-config.json for a long time, but after some of the updates it doesn't work anymore.