# Configuring SSH keys for git to use when not in Git Bash

Tags: git, github, ssh, npm, sublimetext3

I'm fairly new to git and have rarely used anything but Windows for programming.

I've set up a React app using [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app), and used [`gh-pages`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages) to deploy it to my github.io project page.  I've set up an SSH key on my local machine and added it to my github SSH Keys.  Running `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` makes deploying in Git Bash simple without having to enter a username and password.  Great.

However, I'm using [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) for my development, and want to use the [`npm` plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/npm) to run `npm run deploy` right from the editor.  I get the following error:

```
Cloning git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git into node_modules\gh-pages\.cache
Cloning into 'node_modules\gh-pages\.cache'...
Permission denied (publickey).

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Unless I miss my guess, it appears that git doesn't know to use the SSH key automatically, regardless of where it's being run from.  Is there a way to configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to define in your environment variable:

- a `PATH` which includes `<git>/bin` as well as `<git>/usr/bin` (with `<git>` the installation path for the [latest Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases))
  (`usr/bin` does include `ssh.exe`);
- a `HOME` environment variable set to your %USERPROFILE%

Make sure that you see your public/private key in `dir %HOME%\.ssh`

Then launch SublimeText from that session.

Comment: This mostly fixes my issue.  In order for `ssh-add` to work, there need to be two environment variables set which are returned when `ssh-agent -s` is run.  I'm guessing the only way to make it work in Sublime Text is to write a script that pulls those two values from ssh-agent and runs `setx` on them before opening Sublime Text.  Is there a better way?

Comment: @dfoverdx Not that I know of (as illustrated by https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/issues/178 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/36338537/6309). But do you need a private key with a passphrase though?

Comment: I hadn't realized that password-less keys didn't require `ssh-agent` and `ssl-add`.  Thanks for your help!